# No paragraphs for a part of text in editor

Tags: editor

How can I set, if possible, WordPress editor to not insert paragraphs for a part of post entry? I want to use divs inside the post, but W3C Validator gives invalid response.

Comment: Could you provide sample of text?

Comment: Did you try using [raw-html](https://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/) plugin?